# How to move the cursor to the very beginning of the console window in Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I saw someone overwriting a line without the use of `CLS` by using `!CR!` (carriage return character):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a in ('copy /z "%~f0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"
<nul set /p =Hello, world!CR!
<nul set /p =Hi   ,
pause >nul
```

output:

```
Hi   , world
```

`!CR!` moves the cursor to the beginning of the line so either `echo` or `<nul set /p =` can overwrite that line without `CLS`.

What I'm asking is, can I do the exact same thing but for the entire console window (not just a line)? Or, can I move the cursor to the very beginning of the console so I can overwrite everything?

I knew I can just use `CLS` to wipe everything but I hate the flickering `CLS` makes when it deletes everything and then `ECHO` something else immediately.

I'm trying to make an interactive UI in Batch so any possible solutions will help a lot.

Comment: [Move cursor to *any position* using just ECHO command](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7898), [Move cursor to screen home with TIMEOUT command!](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6760)

Comment: @Squashman helpful links, thanks!

Comment: ItsSuperPlayz, I have undone your last [Edit]. If you wish to submit a solution for your own question, there is an answer area provided for exactly that. Solutions do not belong in the question area itself. Additionally, should your own solution become your preferred answer, you can eventually mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `!ESC![<line>;<column>H` into you ECHO output. As well as the function

```
for /F %%a in ('ECHO prompt $E ^| cmd') do (
  SET "ESC=%%a"
)
```

somewhere into your script.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F %%a in ('ECHO prompt $E ^| cmd') do (
  SET "ESC=%%a"
)

ECHO Normal ECHO
ECHO !ESC![3;2HWrite A
ECHO !ESC![6;12HB
ECHO !ESC![4;20HC
ECHO !ESC![1;30HD Note: The cursor will now be in the line after this
ECHO ECHO normal again

PAUSE >NUL
```

Output:

[image: ECHO in row and column]

Alternatively have a look into this tool: https://github.com/TheBATeam/BATBOX-An-Awesome-Batch-Plugin